# Blogger - Retrieve blogs based on Label

Tags: java, blogger

Is there any way to retrieve blogs based on labels? As per blogger API it only supports to retrieve blogs using blogId (specific to a user)

eg:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/blogId/posts
```

returns all post based on blog id.

But is there any way to get all blog based on labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//return all labels
    document.write('<script src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&max-results=0&callback=listlabels"></script>');

//return all posts for label
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/'+encodeURIComponent('label name here')+'?published&alt=json-in-script&callback=listpostsoflabels"><\/script>');
```